# Virtual function inheritance does not work as expected

Tags: system-verilog, virtual-functions

```
module virtual_method;

    // this example is referred to the lab1 class inheritance
    // the purpose is to learn the convenience of the virtual method 
class trans;
    bit[31:0] data;
    int pkt_id;
    int data_nidles;
    int pkt_nidles;
    bit rsp;
    string name;
    virtual function trans clone(trans t = null);
        if (t == null)
                t = new();
        t.data = data;
        t.pkt_id = pkt_id;
        t.data_nidles = data_nidles;
        t.pkt_nidles= pkt_nidles;
        t.rsp = rsp;
        return t;
    endfunction

    virtual function print_f(int i,  name = "tr");
        $display("this is trans class i = %d,name = %s",i,name);
    endfunction
endclass

class ch_trans extends trans;
    int ch_id;
    string name;
    virtual function trans clone(trans t = null);
        ch_trans ct;    
        if (t == null)
            ct = new();
        else
            void'($cast(ct,t));
        ct.ch_id = ch_id;
        return ct;
    endfunction

    virtual function print_f(int i, name = "ch_trans");
        $display("this is ch_trans class i = %d name =%s ",i,name);
    endfunction
endclass

initial begin
    trans t1,t2;
    ch_trans ct1,ct2;
    
    ct1 = new();
    ct1.pkt_id = 2;
    ct1.ch_id = 3;
    $display("ct1 = %p",ct1);
    
    t1 = ct1; 
    t1.print_f(7);
end
endmodule
```

I'm confused why the t1.print(7) function prints name = "tr" not "ch_trans".

I debugged in VCS and found t1.print_f(7) calling the child class print_f function didn't call class trans print_f function.

I think this print "ch_trans"; but it didn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behavior is an [unclear](https://accellera.mantishub.io/view.php?id=1584) issue in the current LRM. Section 8.20 says this about argument defaults:

> It is not necessary to have matching default expressions, but the presence of a default shall match.

The problem is that it does not say anything about which default should be taken, Most tools have chosen the default specified by the type of the class variable being referenced. In this case `t1` defined as the class type `trans`.